# Why doesn't the echo "Hello World!" statement work as expected?

Tags: string, bash, syntax

I'm learning the fundamentals of Bash scripting. If I am not mistaken, strings with no delimitations and delimited by double quotes (`"`) are interpreted almost in the same way and so, as alphanumeric strings; variables inside them are expanded. On the other side, strings delimited by single quotes (`'`) don't expand variables, and this is the main difference comparing them with the previuosly mentioned ones.
Practicing a bit with the terminal, I noticed that one statement doesn't work as I expected. As you can see in this example:

```
MacBook-Pro-di-Rodolfo:~ Rodolfo$ echo Hello World!
Hello World!
MacBook-Pro-di-Rodolfo:~ Rodolfo$ echo 'Hello World!'
Hello World!
MacBook-Pro-di-Rodolfo:~ Rodolfo$ echo "Hello World!"
echo "Hello World"
Hello World
```

the last statement doesn't print out the same string as the previous ones, truncating the exclamation mark. Can anyone explain me the reason of this character removal?
If it can be useful, I am running all this under Mac OS X v. 10.9.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33339/23529

Comment: @DanielJour, so the most elegant solution to avoid this is to use single quotes only, considering that the back slash character doen't work in this case?

Comment: What's wrong with using escaping backslash here? IIRC adjacent strings are concatenated by bash, so something like `"Hello World"'!'` should work, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exclamation marks are used to expand command history if that feature is enabled in Bash. They need to be within single quotes, or escaped using `\!`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/understanding-the-exclamation-mark-in-bash#.

Comment: Note that you can control history expansion: turn it off with `set +H`; re-enable with `set -H`

Answer (score 3):

This is really a comment:

Quoted and unquotes strings differ in a very fundamental way: unquoted strings are subject to further expansion by the shell

**Word splitting**: unquoted strings will be tokenized by the shell, and the tokens are joined with a single space

```
text="my name is
   Inigo   Montoya"
echo "$text"
echo $text
```

outputs

```
my name is
   Inigo   Montoya
my name is Inigo Montoya
```

Note how the whitespace gets collapsed for the unquoted version

**Filename generation**: shell filename patterns (aka "glob" patterns) will be expanded in unquoted strings:

```
text="files *"
echo "$text"
echo $text
```

outputs

```
files *
files [list of all files in your current directory ...]
```

This behaviour can be controlled with `set -f` and `set +f`

---

For all the gory details, read the bash manual:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting
- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions

And this canonical article:

- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

Comment: Just for fun: `( IFS=''; echo $text )`.

Comment: You mean `( IFS=''; set -f; echo $text )` versus `echo "$text"`. Whee, fun!

Comment: Well, I really meant it without `set -f`, but only to illustrate that newlines and consecutive spaces are preserved. (Of course, all of this is a bad idea and should only be used under parental supervision—unless, of course, we killed your father and we should prepare to die).